# Fetch one to many relationship value core data

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm trying to fetch values from core data using a predicate here is part of my model
[image]

This is the predicate that I am using:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = 
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"idPartida == %@ AND obra.idObra == %@",
[NSNumber numberWithInt:[[reportePartida valueForKey:@"idPartida"] intValue]],IdObra];
```

It returns 0, but if I try to make the request just with `idPartida` it works and if I make the request using Obra as Entity an using `idObra` on the predicate it works too, but trying to access to Obra.idObra through the relationship is not working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You want a specific `Partida` and have the `idPartida`, so that is everything you need. All other parts of your predicate would be redundant and unnecessary.

Comment: My question was not about what kind of data i'm try to reach with the predicate, my question is about why, the NSPredicate is not working when i'm trying to acces trough a relationship field

Comment: Well, because it is a redundant and unnecessary predicate. It does not make any sense at all.